# multidimensional array output. Help me extract and loop through this mess please

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I have this awesome MySQL query that's returning me an awesome array >

```
$join_sql = "SELECT $detail_table.`lead_id`, $detail_table.`field_number`, $detail_table.`value` FROM $lead_table JOIN $detail_table ON $lead_table.`id` = $detail_table.`lead_id` WHERE $lead_table.`date_created` BETWEEN '2012-03-18 00:00:00' AND '2012-03-19 23:59:59'";
$join_query = $wpdb->get_results($join_sql, ARRAY_A);
```

This is returning a (in my opinion) complex associate array that looks like this - http://pastebin.com/kpXrK9Ra

(I don't understand data storage methodology but this seems overly complicated to me to have each bit of data in it's own dimensional array rather than just a row of data for each record. But anyway, this is what I have to deal with.)

So here's a small sample of what I need to get to >

```
[23] => Array ( [lead_id] => 3 [field_number] => 6.3 [value] => Jane )
```

So the key that represents a "record" in my mind is the [lead_id].  I need to be able to create a var $first_name.  My resultset may have 50 unique [lead_id} but for the first name, the [field_number] will always be '6.3'.

So how do I loop through the pastebin and create vars for each of the elements so that all the [lead_id] with matching numbers outputs something like-

```
$first_name, $last_name, $whatev, $foo, $bar, $etc
```

I'm not even sure if this makes sense...  :\

EDIT: What I'm trying to do is access the 'field_number' which corresponds to what the field is, ie: a first name, second name, etc. and the corresponding 'value' and output all of those in a particular order that matches the 'lead_id'.  So all lead_id's of [2] would be output into a line of the CSV, and then the next lead_id, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The title of this question is depressingly accurate

Comment: I see what you want to get to, but what is your ideal end result look like?

Comment: Do a `var_export` of the array so we can just copy paste the array and work with it. :)

Comment: Here's the var_export- http://pastebin.com/uMmGjP9y

Comment: @mikevoermans Ultimately I'll be creating the data as a CSV that can be downloaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your input in `$xs`, the following:

```
$ret = array_reduce($xs, function($acc,$x) {
    $acc[$x['lead_id']][$x['field_number']] = $x['value'];
    return $acc;
}, array());
```

produces the output of:

```
array (
  2 => 
  array (
    1 => '37',
    2 => '051000549',
    3 => '1050000605321',
    4 => '1050000605321',
    15 => '250.00',
    '6.3' => 'John',
    '6.6' => 'Doe',
    7 => 'Microscope',
    '8.1' => '1222 McDowell Ave NE',
    '8.3' => 'Roanoke',
    '8.4' => 'Virginia',
    '8.5' => '24012',
    '8.6' => 'United States',
    9 => '(540)265-3216',
    10 => 'marty@microscope.com',
    11 => 'John Doe',
    16 => '987654321',
    '14.1' => 'Authorized',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    1 => '27',
    2 => '987654321',
    3 => '1050000123456',
    4 => '1050000123456',
    15 => '350.00',
    '6.3' => 'Jane',
    '6.6' => 'Doe',
    7 => 'Acme Inc',
    '8.1' => '6724 Laban Rd',
    '8.3' => 'Roanoke',
    '8.4' => 'Virginia',
    '8.5' => '24019',
    '8.6' => 'United States',
    9 => '(540)362-2773',
    10 => 'm@seoserpent.com',
    11 => 'Acme Inc.',
    16 => '987654321',
    '14.1' => 'Authorized',
  ),
)
```

*Update:* The input I used is:

```
$xs = array ( 
 0 => array ( 'lead_id' => '2', 'field_number' => '1', 'value' => '37', ),
 1 => array ( 'lead_id' => '2', 'field_number' => '2', 'value' => '051000549', ),
 2 => array ( 'lead_id' => '2', 'field_number' => '3', 'value' => '1050000605321', ),
 3 => array ( 'lead_id' => '2', 'field_number' => '4', 'value' => '1050000605321', ),
 4 => array ( 'lead_id' => '2', 'field_number' => '15', 'value' => '250.00', ),
 5 => array ( 'lead_id' => '2', 'field_number' => '6.3', 'value' => 'John', ),
 6 => array ( 'lead_id' => '2', 'field_number' => '6.6', 'value' => 'Doe', ),
 7 => array ( 'lead_id' => '2', 'field_number' => '7', 'value' => 'Microscope', ),
 8 => array ( 'lead_id' => '2', 'field_number' => '8.1', 'value' => '1222 McDowell Ave NE', ),
 9 => array ( 'lead_id' => '2', 'field_number' => '8.3', 'value' => 'Roanoke', ),
 10 => array ( 'lead_id' => '2', 'field_number' => '8.4', 'value' => 'Virginia', ),
 11 => array ( 'lead_id' => '2', 'field_number' => '8.5', 'value' => '24012', ),
 12 => array ( 'lead_id' => '2', 'field_number' => '8.6', 'value' => 'United States', ),
 13 => array ( 'lead_id' => '2', 'field_number' => '9', 'value' => '(540)265-3216', ),
 14 => array ( 'lead_id' => '2', 'field_number' => '10', 'value' => 'marty@microscope.com', ),
 15 => array ( 'lead_id' => '2', 'field_number' => '11', 'value' => 'John Doe', ),
 16 => array ( 'lead_id' => '2', 'field_number' => '16', 'value' => '987654321', ),
 17 => array ( 'lead_id' => '2', 'field_number' => '14.1', 'value' => 'Authorized', ),
 18 => array ( 'lead_id' => '3', 'field_number' => '1', 'value' => '27', ),
 19 => array ( 'lead_id' => '3', 'field_number' => '2', 'value' => '987654321', ),
 20 => array ( 'lead_id' => '3', 'field_number' => '3', 'value' => '1050000123456', ),
 21 => array ( 'lead_id' => '3', 'field_number' => '4', 'value' => '1050000123456', ),
 22 => array ( 'lead_id' => '3', 'field_number' => '15', 'value' => '350.00', ),
 23 => array ( 'lead_id' => '3', 'field_number' => '6.3', 'value' => 'Jane', ),
 24 => array ( 'lead_id' => '3', 'field_number' => '6.6', 'value' => 'Doe', ),
 25 => array ( 'lead_id' => '3', 'field_number' => '7', 'value' => 'Acme Inc', ),
 26 => array ( 'lead_id' => '3', 'field_number' => '8.1', 'value' => '6724 Laban Rd', ),
 27 => array ( 'lead_id' => '3', 'field_number' => '8.3', 'value' => 'Roanoke', ),
 28 => array ( 'lead_id' => '3', 'field_number' => '8.4', 'value' => 'Virginia', ),
 29 => array ( 'lead_id' => '3', 'field_number' => '8.5', 'value' => '24019', ),
 30 => array ( 'lead_id' => '3', 'field_number' => '8.6', 'value' => 'United States', ),
 31 => array ( 'lead_id' => '3', 'field_number' => '9', 'value' => '(540)362-2773', ),
 32 => array ( 'lead_id' => '3', 'field_number' => '10', 'value' => 'm@seoserpent.com', ),
 33 => array ( 'lead_id' => '3', 'field_number' => '11', 'value' => 'Acme Inc.', ),
 34 => array ( 'lead_id' => '3', 'field_number' => '16', 'value' => '987654321', ),
 35 => array ( 'lead_id' => '3', 'field_number' => '14.1', 'value' => 'Authorized', ),
 );
```

Also, you may find a `foreach` or `while` loop more readable than `array_reduce`:

```
$ret = array();
foreach ($xs as $x) {
    $ret[$x['lead_id']][$x['field_number']] = $x['value'];
}
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I'm trying to do.  Not sure about the value of $xs though.  I changed it for me to $join_query from my example but that just returns NULL on a var_dump.  Can you advise?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the input, maybe there's some subtle difference.